# Can you purchase legendaries from vending machines?

Tags: borderlands-3

In Borderlands 2 it was possible to find legendaries in vending machines. I am wondering if it is still the case in borderlands 3. Are vendors like Earl also able to sell legendary anointed gear?

If so, what is the loot pool and respective drop rates?

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to get information about the loot pool and the appearance rate in the game, unless it's datamined or the information is revealed by the developers.

Comment: @senpai that isn't true. This is a yes/no question, not a question of the actual drop rates. If there are any observations about legendary loot from vending machines that would satisfy the question posed. The answer does not require datamining.

Comment: The question of the loot pool will always change as new dlcs are added and released, and changes are made to the game

Answer (score 3):

Legendary items are now occasionally available in vending machines. They can show up as the "[item of the day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9hWM.jpg)" and [regular items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI3yq.jpg). Mayhem levels are applied as well, as  you can see in the screenshots. This was a change added with the [7/23/2020 patch](https://borderlands.com/en-US/news/2020-07-23-borderlands-3-patch-hotfixes-july-23/) which states:

> Legendary Gear available in Vending Machines
>
> We have rebalanced vending machines based on community feedback.
> Vending machines of all types have a small chance of providing
> Legendary gear for purchase.

Previously, legendaries were available during special events like the [Door Busters mini-event](https://borderlands.com/en-US/news/2020-03-27-co-op-loot-drop/) that ran from 3/27/2020 to 4/2/2020 which enabled legendaries to be reliably found in most vending machines.
Here is an example of two legendaries in one machine: [a Techspert and a Big Boom Blaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIUBC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the games current state it is not possible to get legendaries in a vending machine. It is possible however, to get legendaries out of the golden chest.

Edit: I forgot, it is possible to get a legendary in the "item of the day -slot" or whatever it is called but i dont have any rates.

> Legendary Items can be Sold
>
> On some rare chances, Legendary Items can be sold as the Item of the Day. >These will cost a lot more money so you might need to farm for them.

Source : https://gamewith.net/borderlands-3/article/show/11415

Comment: Any source for this information?

Comment: Answer was edited.

Comment: If the source isn’t official it’s worthless less there is a screenshot or video proof of some sort.

Comment: I know for sure you can get some from the vending machine that takes the special currency on the sanctuary

Comment: I don't check the Crazy Earl shop often, so maybe you can get legendaries from there. But me and 2 other friends have played through the story 2 times each and farmed a fair bit of end game content and haven't seen any legendaries in shops. I also haven't seen anyone share an image of one. Also the source linked is a pretty bad source of BL3 info. They make out many of the legendaries to be exclusive to certain bosses when really a lot of the bosses have massive loot pools that overlap with other bosses and it just so happened to drop that specific legendary for the article writer.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen people say they’ve bought them from machines, but I’ve yet to see it.  I’m level 53, and I haven’t seen them in regular machines, or the one right outside Earl’s door.  I’ve also never received one in the golden key chest either.  I’ve only ever picked them up as loot.

Edit:  well, as of today with the new update, things have changed.  Both machines in Sanctuary have legendaries for sale now.  Yay!!

Answer (score 0):

You can currently due to a short timed event that is currently going on. There is only one per machine.

https://borderlands.com/en-US/news/2020-03-26-borderlands-legendary-collection/

However, as mentioned in the comments, the loot tables change all the time.